# Google sheets wrap cell content in other content

Tags: google-sheets

Im looking to create a formula in one column that takes the content from the adjacent column and wraps it inside some other content, can anyone help with this?

For example, given:

```
           A     |     B
    1|           | someText1
    2|           | someText2
    3|           | someText3
    4|           | someText4
```

expected outcome content for Col A, after applying appropriate formula:

```
                A        |     B
    1| wrap("someText1") | someText1
    2| wrap("someText2") | someText2
    3| wrap("someText3") | someText3
    4| wrap("someText4") | someText4
```

I hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Simply use `="wrap(""" &B1&""")"` in column A.

Comment: Thanks @MewX, that likely would work. Havent tried it. Came back here to post my solution that i discovered

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing:  Add a function and applied it to the whole column A

```
    function getAdjacentValue() {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var col = range.getColumn();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
    return 'wrap("'+range2.getValue()+'")';
    }
```

Comment: Using a single-cell custom function in multiple cells will lead to performance issues at scale. When a custom function is needed, make it process an array, as [recommended by Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization).

Answer (score 0):

By combining MewX suggestion with  `arrayformula` one can achieve the same for all column, with one formula:

```
=arrayformula("wrap(""" & B1:B4 & """)")
```

Explanation: `&` is the string concatenation operator, quote marks within a string are escaped by doubling them.